# Which HTML5 canvas game library has hover support?

Tags: html5-canvas, libraries

I'm going to build a simple game using HTML5 canvas. Instead of doing everything manually, I decided to use some library. I see there are many (over 100) libraries out there and have checked out some 5-6 of them, however none seem to support the simple "hover" effect like the one you have in a browser.

Basically, I want to have a bunch of images or text "sprites" which should change when mouse hovers over them to indicate to the user that he can do something with it. And those elements should also be clickable.

Please, do not suggest that I use DOM. I want to use Canvas because I have some complex graphics/animations.

Last thing I checked was Cocos2d, it's MenuItem seemed to have some potential: easy to implement click handlers, two images - one for pressed and other for depressed (normal) state. But I don't see how could I create a hover effect.

I would prefer something like jQuery approach:

```
SpriteElement.hover(function() { do stuff });
```

Comment: why wouldn't you use jQuery then?

Comment: Nathan, because jQuery is for DOM elements, not `<canvas>` graphics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I installed, tested, and read docs. Here's what I've found:

**KineticJS**

element.on("mouseover", function () {    });

**Easel.js**

element.addEventListener("mouseover", function() { } );

Additionaly, Easel.js has nice [ButtonHelper](http://www.backwardcompatible.net/169-hover-effect-mouse-button-image-html5-canvas-easeljs) class which automates using 3 different images for normal, hover, pressed state.

**Crafty.js**

element.bind('MouseOver', ...

**MelonJS**

No automatic support. [Manually](http://www.melonjs.org/demos/sample4/MouseEvent.html) it can be done using:

input.registerMouseEvent('mousemove')

and then iterating child elements and checking via this.collisionBox.containsPoint(me.input.mouse.pos)

**Quintus**

Apparently, [no support](https://plus.google.com/communities/104292074755089084725/stream/1ecd1fcc-6447-4a93-b78b-f5031340b410)

**Lime.js**

Couldn't find anything in docs or googling.

**CanvasEngine**

element.on("mouseover", function(e) { } );

Seems to be buggy though on Firefox 20.0 the event fires only when mouse stops moving.

**Cocos2D-html5**

No automattic support, only manually iterating children. Code seems to be in flux because Cocos is focused on touch devices which have no "hover" concept.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is probably called *mouse over*.

KineticJS supports it:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9270417/315168